# Maven build fetching wrong dependencies

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I downloaded the follwoing repocitories

1. https://github.com/wso2/carbon-device-mgt
2. https://github.com/wso2/carbon-device-mgt-plugins
3. https://github.com/wso2/product-emm

I have done modification to the repository [1].
Then i have build the repositories using maven in given order [1], [2] and [3].

I cant access the new functions created in repository [1] from repository [3]. 
Any idea why? I am new to maven.

Comment: Can you please provide us with more inside. error logs. make user to use "mvn clean install" when building the repositories.
If you are using the master branch its advisable to use the released 2.0.1 or 2.1.0-alpha branch since the master branch is under development.

Comment: A long list of
Dashboard.java:[468,41] error: unreported exception DataAccessLayerException; must be caught or declared to be th

Dashboard.java:[509,76] error: unreported exception DataAccessLayerException; must be caught or declared to be th

Dashboard.java:[583,14] error: exception SQLException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement

Comment: and there was no error log. It Just did not see my new packages and functions .

Comment: which components have you modified in [1]?

Comment: https://github.com/wso2/carbon-device-mgt.  I added a package and some class files in the Common and the Core

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the instructions given in the below webinar and the tutorial to create your feature as an OSGI bundle(Carbon component) and add it to the EMM server. This is the correct and advisable approach for including new functionalities to WSO2 products.

http://wso2.com/premium/webinars/creating-your-own-wso2-carbon-components
http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2014/03/how-to-write-a-wso2-carbon-component/